# Playback ROS1 bag files in ROS2

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the method to playback rosbag files recorded from ROS melodic in ROS2 Humble running on Ubuntu 22.04?

I know the existence of ros1_bridge, but it seems for this to work I must install ROS1 and ROS2 side by side in the same computer. With ROS2 Humble only being available for Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS1 Melodic not being supported in Ubuntu 22.04 make the usage of ros1_bridge impossible, right? Or am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402302/playback-ros1-bag-files-in-ros2/) by [jclinton830](https://answers.ros.org/users/38971/jclinton830/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2022-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I was right in my assumption but I found some information about this problem and a fix by following the how to guide on ROS2 humble documentation website. This shows how to use ros1_bridge with ROS2 Humble in Ubuntu 22.04. Below is the link to the solution. I hope a neater approach will be made possible soon.

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Using-ros1_bridge-Jammy-upstream.html

---

Originally posted by [jclinton830](https://answers.ros.org/users/38971/jclinton830/) with karma: 91 on 2022-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qilin_gundamenjoyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/105678/qilin_gundamenjoyer/) on 2022-06-16**:
I know this problem has been solved but I think this [rosbag](https://gitlab.com/ternaris/rosbags) would be of use to you in the future! It's a pure python library that provides read-write access to both ros1 bags and ros2 bags during their conversion!

**Comment by [jclinton830](https://answers.ros.org/users/38971/jclinton830/) on 2022-06-16**:
Yes that is exactly what I need. Thanks.

**Comment by [SimJon1](https://answers.ros.org/users/148254/simjon1/) on 2023-05-09**:
I did try to install ros1_bridge and ros2 humble following the docmentation you posted. However after building ros2 from source and removing packages.ros.org from the sources.list, the error that should be fixed by removing the file from the source.list still keeps occuring: "The following packages have unmet dependecies: ros-core-dev: Depends: catkin but it is not installabe E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
How did you solve this?